# Connect to Sun ONC RPC server from Linux

Tags: python, c, linux, rpc

I am looking for solutions to create a RPC client in Linux that can connect to Sun ONC RPC server.
The server is written in C.

I would like to know if I can:

1. Create an RPC client in Linux
2. Create the RPC client in Python

Answer (score 0):

You can use the OpenSource [gsoap](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gsoap2/):

You can create with gsoap RPC(s) in C. And if you want to do it in Python you have just to develeop api template in C and then call it from python

Comment: I do not the onc RPC. but I know that RPC uses soap standard to communicate. if it's the case then it will works*

Comment: there is a simple example to see how gsoap works. it's in the sample folder. it's the calc example

Answer (score 0):

An ONC RPC client can be created by using the `.idl` file and `rpcgen`. The original RPC protocol precedes SOAP by several years.

Yes, you can create the RPC client in linux (see rpcgen)

Yes, you can create the RPC client in python (please see pep-0384)

Answer (score 0):

It can be done.  There are couple of ways to do it.

First one is to use Sun ONC RPC functions developed in Python.  Take a look at

http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Demo/rpc/rpc.py

I believe it implements most of them.  The equivalent of C XDR encode/decode routines generated by rpcgen from the .x file would need to be hand written in Python, i.e. packer and unpacker.

The second alternative is to take the Sun ONC RPC C client functions generated by rpcgen and create Extension Module that can be used with Python.